# Getting matches from a query and not keeping anything else

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I have two datasets where I'm reading in two tables from an Access database. I want to be able to match up the data by EXPRESSION so it keeps all the matching "SN's" and gets rid of the ones that don't have a match. So far my code is keeping all of the "SN's". Here it is,

```
con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="+filePath);
con3 = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="+filePath);

if ((string)comboBox1.SelectedItem == "CGA0112")
{
    try
    {
         string end = "ENDDATE";
         string qual = "CGA0112";
         string start = "START";

         ad.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT b.RSV_CAT, b.SEQNUM, b.LEASE,
                             b.WELL_ID, a.QUALIFIER, a.KEYWORD, a.EXPRESSION 
                            FROM [AC_ECONOMIC] a INNER JOIN [AC_PROPERTY] b
                              on a.PROPNUM=b.PROPNUM WHERE a.KEYWORD = '" +end+ "' 
                   AND a.QUALIFIER = '" +qual+ "' AND a.EXPRESSION LIKE 'SN%'", con); 

       ds.Clear();
       ad.Fill(ds);

       con.Open();
       ad.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
       con.Close();

       ad3.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT b.RSV_CAT, b.SEQNUM, b.LEASE, 
                               b.WELL_ID, a.QUALIFIER, a.KEYWORD, a.EXPRESSION 
                               FROM [AC_ECONOMIC] a INNER JOIN [AC_PROPERTY] b 
                              on a.PROPNUM=b.PROPNUM 
                              WHERE a.KEYWORD = '" + start + "' AND a.QUALIFIER = '" + 
                               qual + "' AND a.EXPRESSION LIKE 'SN%'", con3);
       ds3.Clear();
       ad3.Fill(ds3);

       ds.Merge(ds3); //merges the two datasets together

       win1.frm1 = this;
       win1.Show();

       con3.Open();
       ad3.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
       con3.Close();
     }
```

I was wondering if there was a possible solution to this so it only keeps the matching EXPRESSIONS. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Rather then merging the datasets, could you use a LINQ Join against the Rows collections?

Comment: @CjS. I'm not sure how I would go about doing that.

Comment: I added an example as an answer.  Should get you pretty close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example.  Since "SN456" appears in both tables, it is selected in the result.

```
        var ds = new DataSet();
        var table1 = ds.Tables.Add("Table1");
        table1.Columns.Add("Expression", typeof (string));
        table1.Rows.Add("SN123");
        table1.Rows.Add("SN456");
        table1.Rows.Add("SN789");
        var table2 = ds.Tables.Add("Table2");
        table2.Columns.Add("Expression", typeof (string));
        table2.Rows.Add("SN000");
        table2.Rows.Add("SN456");
        table2.Rows.Add("SN999");

        var table1Rows = table1.AsEnumerable();
        var table2Rows = table2.AsEnumerable();

        var matches = table1Rows.Join(table2Rows, l => l["Expression"], r => r["Expression"], (l, r) => l["Expression"]);
        foreach (var match in matches)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(match);
        }
```

Comment: I dont think this would work either because I'm filling the datasets with the data from the Access database

Comment: This code doesn't depend on Access.  Your filling your datasets from Access, but the join happens in code.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get all the SN's that are in both tables? if so You should try a sub query like this one.

```
    "SELECT b.RSV_CAT, b.SEQNUM, b.LEASE,
    b.WELL_ID, a.QUALIFIER, a.KEYWORD, a.EXPRESSION 
    FROM [AC_ECONOMIC] a INNER JOIN [AC_PROPERTY] b
    on a.PROPNUM=b.PROPNUM WHERE a.KEYWORD = '" +end+ "' 
    AND a.QUALIFIER = '" +qual+ "' AND a.EXPRESSION IN 
   (SELECT a.EXPRESSION FROM [AC_ECONOMIC] a INNER JOIN [AC_PROPERTY] b on 
    a.PROPNUM=b.PROPNUM WHERE a.KEYWORD = '" + start + "' AND a.QUALIFIER = '" + qual  
    + "' AND  a.EXPRESSION LIKE 'SN%'", con3);
```

this should give you those matches. this code will give you all SN's that are both tables with the two different keyword.

Comment: The SN's are on the same table they just have different KEYWORDS such as end and start

Comment: I don't think a correlated subquery will work since the source tables exist in different databases.  I'm not an Access guy, so maybe there's a "Linked Table" way of doing it that I just don't understand.

Comment: Yeah this didnt work for me it gave me, "You have written a subquery that can return more than one field without using the EXISTS reserved word in the main query's FROM clause. Revise the SELECT statement of the subquery to request only one field.

Comment: I have updated the code to only get the one field back try the updated version of the code now.